# git unable to find certificate in keychain after updating to macOS Sierra

Tags: git, macos, ssl, macos-sierra

After upgrading to macOS 10.12 Sierra I'm unable to sync with my encrypted SSL git server. The certificate still works fine while accessing the server through Safari.

I get this message when trying to push to the server:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://....': SSL: Can't find the certificate "...." and its private key in the Keychain.
```

The certificate is there in the keychain, and the name is correct (it worked before the update), but somehow I can't access it.

My ~/.gitconfig file still consists of this:

```
[http "https://...."]
    sslCert = ....
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

Have anyone else bumped into this problem so far?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the **git-credential-osxkeychain** helper application is broken on macOS sierra and will not retrieve any more a user certificate that is returned with **security find-identities**

The only workaround I found is to

- export the certificate and key from keychain to my_certificate.p12
- edit .git/config for the affected account to use

  ```
  [http]
    sslCert = /Users/foo/certificates/my_certificate.p12
    sslcertpasswordprotected = true
  ```

Note: You'll need a password on the P12 and have to enter the password for the p12 every time you do a git command.

P.S: RADAR://28461462

Comment: Great! That workaround still works, but does anyone know of any progress in this issue?

Comment: Why do you think that this is related to git-credential-osxkeychain? Can't see any code that would handle certificates in there https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/osxkeychain/git-credential-osxkeychain.c

Comment: It looks like a fix is underway in the CURL repo:

Comment: Great find, looks like your link broke: https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1105 I think it would be helpful to update your answer.

Comment: Hi @ThomasEngelmeier is this your website? http://web.archive.org/web/20020204014027/http://engelmeier.com:80/developer/ToolPostLinker.html can you help me Find ToolFrontEnd?
Context: https://github.com/tengelmeier/tengelmeier.github.io/pull/1

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a crt and keyfile

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
    sslCert = my.crt
    sslKey = my.key
```

you need to install curl and git with openssl support

```
brew install openssl
brew install curl --with-openssl
brew install git --with-brewed-openssl --with-brewed-curl
```

That's worked for me as expected

Comment: Thx! That works on Sierra, although effectively does not use mac OS security mechanisms altogether now and brew explicitly states, that openssl is unsupported under mac OS.

Comment: `brew install curl --with-openssl` returns `invalid option: --with-openssl`

Answer (score 0):

Simple ssh-add helped me with this ;)

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to uninstall

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew uninstall curl
brew uninstall git
```

after installing as @trollr mentioned

```
brew install openssl
brew install curl --with-openssl
brew install git --with-brewed-openssl --with-brewed-curl
```

, you also have to ensure that the right git version (there are MAAAAAANY available, see

```
find / -name git
```

)

Homebrew tells you where it puts the new brewed git version, for example

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.10.2/bin/git
```

check your version with
which git

or just call the absolute path to ensure using the right version, like

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.10.2/bin/git clone .......
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
git -c http.sslCert=/Users/user/Documents/gittest/cert.p12 -c http.sslcertpasswordprotected=true clone https://gitlab.domain.com/user/repository.git
```

you can add more verbose debuggin by adding

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2
```

in front of the command.

The certificates are in the keychain and are marked trusted. Also the CA certificate is present.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue with "Can't find the certificate.." error message has been solved for me after changing the certificate name to a string containing no other characters than Latin letters. I.e. renaming "my_cert.p12" to "mysert.p12" has really helped to get rid of this error.